# Tower of Hanoi variation - Split into two towers of odd and even disks

Tags: recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Suppose we have three rods `A`, `B` and `C`, and rod `A` contains `n` disks (Exactly like the original Tower of Hanoi problem). The disks are numbered `1` to `n`, when the bottom disk is number `1` and the top disk is number `n`.

I want to build two towers: One on rod `B` which contains only the odd numbered disks and one on rod `C` which contains only the even numbered disks. The laws of disk moving is exactly like in the original problem.

I am trying to think if it is possible to solve it with only three rods, and if it is how can it be solved recursively.

I thought about moving the top two disks by hand (maybe depends on the parity of `n`) and then perform a recursive call, but I am not sure at all how to do it.

Comment: In your solution, you said that: "moving top two disks by hand". In the Tower of Hanoi problem, this is not allowed. You can only move one disk at a time.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami For your first comment: I want to build two new towers with all of the disks: the odd disks to `B` and the even disks to `C`. For your second comment: I meant to move both disks one a time (maybe in three moves, but I am not sure how).

Comment: Do you want minimum number of moves?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Not necessarily, a simple recursive algorithm (like the simple and intuitive algorithm for the original problem) is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_i$ be the tower defined by disks: $i,\dotsc,n$.

Here is a simple recursive algorithm:

```
Initialize i := 1
while(i != n+1)
    If i is even: 
           move the tower T(i+1) on any rod other than C using the standard Tower of Hanoi algorithm. 
           move disk i to rod C
    else:
           move the tower T(i+1) on any rod other than B using the standard Tower of Hanoi algorithm. 
           move disk i to rod B
    i <- i+1
end
```

Comment: Note that in this case, for $i < j$, disk $i$ is smaller than disk $j$. However, I think that makes the algorithm easier to write than in the case of the original post where disk $1$ was the largest.

Comment: @Nathaniel right. I have edited the answer. Thanks!